# ASP.NET Application with Angular not working with Dev Tunnels

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core, dev-tunnels

**Reproduction steps:**

- In Visual Studio 2022 create a new project with template "ASP.NET Core with Angular". Choose .NET 7.0 when asked.
- Add a new Dev Tunnel and start the website using this tunnel.

**Expected behaviour:**
One would expect that the site ran without an issue like it works with projects using the old SPA configuration (.NET 5 and before). Also nothing I can find on this particular issue.

Is there someone that knows how I can get this to work?

Comment: It's not really answering the question, but dev tunnels are in preview, so a) it might be better log a github issue and b) you might like to try [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) as a more mature solution